# How to make API request javascript code with using api_key?

Tags: javascript, api

I made API request in Python.

```
import requests

key = 'my key'

params = {
  "file1" : 'file'
}

headers = {
  "Authorization" : "Bearer {}".format(key)
}

r = requests.get('url', params=params, headers=headers)

json_response = r.content.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
writeFile =open('samples.json', 'w')
writeFile.write(json_response)
writeFile.close()
print(r.json())
```

I want to make API request in javascript using ajax,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    var key = 'my key';
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'url',
        headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer "+ (key)},
        data : {"file1" : 'files'}
        ,success : function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    })

})
</script>
```

But it doesn't work with this error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url?file1=files' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

And the server returns this status

"OPTIONS url?file1=file HTTP/1.1" 200 -

What should I do?

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: this is not a problem with your api_key but with your server configuration. You need to allow `cors` in your backend

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way, take out your key and header code and see if the same message persists, if it does, you might be aware that this problem should be solved on the applications backend (server-side), by managing cors access, if you don't have backend access, try using an extesion to mozzila's browser (firefox), called 'CORS Everywhere', turn it on and try again but keep mind that is just a temporary manner to solve this. Good Luck